# Calling function from an ListFragment from the MainActivity when the Fragment isn't being used

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I am not sure if that title makes a lot of sense, kind of hard to explain what I want, but I'll give it a go.

I have to fragment, ListFragment and MyFragment. If the device is in portrait, i.e. both fragments can't fit on the screen together then only LisFragment is shown. I have an activity called MyActivity which hosts the fragments and displays the relevant fragment for the relevant device orientation.

The user can then press a button to perform a search using startActivityForResult which then does a call to function within MyActivity to actually perform what is required.

If the phone is in landscape, i.e. both fragments are visible it successfully calls the function from within the PasswordList fragment. However, if the phone is in portrait, the ListFragment is null so the function doesn't get called. Below is the code that I am having the problem with

```
public void performSearch(ArrayList<Spanned> passwords) {
    PasswordList passwordList = (PasswordList)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.passwordListFragment);
    passwordList.performingSearch = true;
    passwordList.performSearch(passwords);
}
```

The PasswordList is the ListFragment that I am talking about above, when the phone is in landscape passwordList works and I can perform the performSearch function. If the phone is portrait even though the ListFragment is being shown it returns Null so the performSearch can't be performed.

How can I perform the performSearch function in either way. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I did Android, but I believe since the fragment is not actually displayed, in your case, it is not existent at this point. I believe each time you switch orientation, the views are redrawn,etc.

This function is in another fragment, is there anyway you can just extract it into another class? In one of my previous android projects, i used two fragments, but for phones/small devices, I had it just forward it to a FragmentActivity (I used the compat library) which hosted the 2nd fragment.On the table version, the 2nd fragment was displayed.

It's not super elegant, and somewhat old, but my project is open sourced and at www.github.com/zerkz if you want to take a look.

Comment: I could potentially move the function to a new class but the function modifies the controls of the user interface. Although I could access the control using PasswordList passwordList = new PasswordList(); and then passwordList.performSearch() but this would create a new instance so anything controls in that function wouldn't modify the UI controls that are actually being displayed

Comment: Are you using setRetainInstance()? I saw this on another answer to a related issue.

Comment: I'm not no, never heard of that